# Python pipenv Unable to import 'matplotlib.pyplot'

Tags: python, matplotlib, module, python-import

Just starting to learn matplotlib and I'm getting an error when importing the module. I'm using a pipenv environment. I think pylint might be pointing to my global Python installation rather than my pipenv environment. When I install matplotlib in my global python installation it works fine.

This is the error: Unable to import 'matplotlib.pyplot'

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

squares = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(squares)

plt.show()
```

Thanks all

Comment: Is matplotlib installed in your pipenv environment? How are you running your code? Are you inside the  pipenv environment when you run it?

Comment: @jfaccioni I'm running this in my pipenv environment via the green run button vscode. It's listed in my pipfile under packages so I assume it is installed correctly in my pipenv environment?

Comment: Run the terminal command `pipenv install` from the folder containing the pipfile to ensure that all packages in there get installed.

Comment: @jfaccioni Done, no luck. Still get the no module named 'matplotlib' error.

Comment: @jfaccioni So, some more information. I tried installing matplotlib by deactivating my pipenv environment and  just using pip install matplotlib and it worked fine.

Comment: Sounds to me like vscode isn't actually running your pipenv environment, but your global Python environment instead. I can't really help you because I don't use vscode.

Comment: @jfaccioni Okay no problem, thanks for your help anyway!